# No module named 'djangosite' when trying to use manage.py

Tags: django, python-3.7

I am using Django 3.0 and python 3.7 to run my Django server, it has only just stopped working and was working before.

The full error is [here](https://pastebin.com/RTWWNcn7) That was running `python3 manage.py runserver` and it is the same for any commands with manage.py

I have tried with and without my virtual environment and have reinstalled Django but it hasn't changed

the only place where  `djangosite` is mentioned is in `manage.py` which I haven't changed

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'djangosite.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Django is installed and I can run other sites

File tree is [here](https://pastebin.com/ne2XZWGx)

Comment: Were you using django or django-sites previously . pip install django-sites?

Comment: @AjayTomGeorge I've in only ever used Django but I'll install django-sites and try again
Update: it said `Requirement already satisfied` and gave the same error when I ran it

Comment: "I am using python 8" => Really ?-)

Comment: *facepalm* im using 3.8, im just going to fix that...

Comment: Where do you use `djangosite` in your code?

Comment: @Alasdair I dont use it, the only place it is is in django's `manage.py`
here `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'djangosite.settings')`

Comment: In that case it probably doesn’t have anything to do with `django-sites`. Please show the layout of the files and directories in your Django project.

Comment: @Alasdair I have edited the post, have a look

Comment: The file tree doesn't show `settings.py` anywhere. If it doesn't exist at `djangosite/settings.py` (relative to `manage.py`), then the import is going to fail.

Comment: @Alasdair it does exist, I deleted some files on the tree that weren't related to it (git etc) and I must have accidentally deleted it

Comment: If you update the file listing then I'll take another look at it, but I don't have any more suggestions.

Comment: You can try moving the settings.py file inside the `home` folder in your file tree and renaming `home` folder to `djangosite`. [default structure](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project)

Comment: @stackoverflowusrone i created it again and it worked, I think it was because the `settings,py` was in the top directory with manage.py not in the mysite folder with the `urls.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had incorrect file structure. The `settings.py` was in the main folder with `manage.py`
It should have been in the mysite folder that has the main `urls.py` etc.

I fixed it by just re-creating the Django project and copying my apps and static file directory

Answer (score 0):

You don't have Django installed or it is not available in your PYTHONPATH.

Perhaps you just did not activate your virtualenv in command shell.

Comment: django is installed and the virtualenv is open, i have checked